# Why Na/C2H5OH not preferred in the reduction of carboxylic acid, despite being used for the reduction of esters

Tags: organic-chemistry

why is Na/C2H5OH  not preferred in the reduction of carboxylic acid to alcohols, despite being used for esters?

Comment: You could get deprotonation as a side reaction, because the reagent generates a strong protic base (ethoxide ion).

Comment: Correct. You get the sodium carboxylate which does not reduce.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the comments point out: the sodium in ethanol generates sodium ethoxide, just as sodium in water generates the hydroxide.  The ethoxide ion, acting as a strong base, deprotonates the acid to a salt and thwarts the reduction.  Get rid of the easily removed proton by using an ester and you unleash the reduction reaction you want.